# Show tooltip when fragment inside viewpager is visible to user

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I need execute a method when the fragment is visible (to the user). This method used for showing tooltip inside fragment.

I've 1 activity has viewpager and menubar at bottom of layout to navigate a fragments. And also i disable swipe for viewpager.

I need to call showTooltip() when fragment is visible or active . i've tried with on resume and setUserVisibleHint() but still not working. Tooltips not appear when viewpager move to visible page.

```
public void showTooltip(){
    Tooltip.make(getActivity(),
    new Tooltip.Builder(101)
    .anchor(gridSearch, Tooltip.Gravity.CENTER)
    .closePolicy(new Tooltip.ClosePolicy()
    .insidePolicy(true, false)
    .outsidePolicy(true, false), 3000)
    .activateDelay(1500)
    .showDelay(300)
    .text("Click to see all videos.")
    .maxWidth(500)
    .withArrow(true)
    .withOverlay(true)
    .floatingAnimation(Tooltip.AnimationBuilder.DEFAULT)
    .build()
     ).show();
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same issue, I need to show to the 2nd tab fragment, but it is showing to the 1st tab fragment once returned to the 1st fragment.

Answer (score 0):

To be noticed that fragment is showing you can use `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` that have callback, that called when you switch `ViewPager`s pages:

```
 mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int i) {
        //here you can show yours tooltip
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

    }
});
```

Comment: tooltips will anchor to some view in fragment . if i call it in pageselected it will return error null pointer of view . @mohax

Comment: @IbnuHabibie, you can call a fragments method in onPageSelected. You can get fragment from fragmentManager, from list, where you store it or use some message system to send message to fragment. I.e. EventBus or Otto libs or android buildIn features as LocalBroadcatManager or Handler